# Is it possible to use floating point texture with p5.js + GLSL?

Tags: glsl, textures, p5.js

I am working on physarum simulation with P5 and GLSL.
I use one separate shader and to calculate particle positions and another for trail diffusion and decay.

I set `P5.Graphics` buffer as a texture uniform in the particle shader. As far as I understand, it is `Uint8ClampedArray` limited to the value range **0-255**. It is not precise enough for particle simulation and I get a grid [looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3osUm.png).

Is it possible to set a floating point texture (something like `float32array`) as a `sampler2D` uniform variable using `P5.js`?